# Java JDBC avoiding redundant code in methods writing to database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Employees is an object listed in another class. It has the fields `name`, `department`, and `experience`. I use the main method to create a Swing object, take in any new employees, and call upon the `addEmployees` class.

What If I want to create more methods in this class that call to the database? Do I need to create a `try/catch`, set the variable 'connector', the whole process again? 
What if I want to create a method in the same class that only sets the `name` and `department`? Do I need to add redundant code?

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
```

public class AddEmployees {

```
public String addEmployee(String name, String department, int experience){



    Connection connector = null; 
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Load a connection to my DB
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myjobsite";
            connector = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "golden", "password");
            String sql="INSERT INTO employees(name,department,experience) values(?,?,?)";
            stmt = connector.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, name);
            stmt.setString(2, department);
            stmt.setInt(3, experience);
            stmt.execute();      //run sql 


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return "Connection Failure";

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "Executed sql";


}
```

}

Comment: I think this question is probably not specific enough to get a good answer on SO.  In general, you can open the connection once at program startup, then pass the connection to `addEmployees` or any other database-access methods you write.

Comment: One connection in a shared app wouldn't be a good idea.  A better solution is to use a connection pool, pass a connection into each method, and use it in the narrowest scope possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct to avoid repeated code is a good one.  DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) should be a bedrock fundamental for all programmers.

Rather than write an entire persistence tier from scratch, I'd recommend beginning with Spring and its JdbcTemplate.  They've done a great job of designing an API that lets you concentrate on just what you need for your application.

Comment: I tried. When i tried to add the validator dependency in maven for a project it wasnt building, not much experience with maven tbh. Is using a gradle build easier?

Comment: I would say Maven and Gradle are equivalent.  Your Maven issue is a separate question.  Try Spring Boot and its guides: https://spring.io/guides

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters you can just put the connection part in its own method like this:

```
public void connectToDb(){
try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Load a connection to my DB
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myjobsite";
            connector = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "golden", "password");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return "Connection Failure";

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then you can call this method whenever you try to start a  database session, this way you can separate the actual connection from the queries you have to  write:

```
public String employeMethod(){
      connectToDb();
      //write your query stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add Spring to your project then you can use [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) to greatly simplify database access code.

Your code can look like this:

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO employees(name,department,experience) values(?,?,?)",
        getName(), getDepartment(), getExperience());
```